# Displaying Monthly Attendance Date Wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to display attendance data in monthly format using PIVOT. But unable to figure out how it should be done.

Below is my table structure

Attendance:

```
AttendanceID    EmployeeID     AttendanceDateTime
```

Employee:

```
EmployeeID     EmployeeName
```

Holiday:

```
HolidayID     HolidayDate
```

Leave:

```
LeaveID    EmployeeID    LeaveDateTime    IsApproved
```

I want to display result like below from the data provided in above table

```
EmployeeName    01-09-2016    02-09-2016    03-09-2016    04-09-2016
     A           Present        Absent        Holiday        Leave
```

Comment: What do you mean "unable to figure out how"? What have you tried?

Comment: @ZLK I tried writing queries with INNER JOIN's but I don't know how to do PIVOT to get the dates in columns and also make out Present / Absent / Leave / Holiday populated accordingly. I'm not getting how can I transform row wise data of Attendance Table to columns as in Dates using PIVIOT

Comment: You're looking for some sort of pivot query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. I don't know the best way to do this. But a simple google search revealed that it can be done with PIVOT Query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the first thing you probably want to do before creating a pivot on dates is figure out what dates you want to pivot. For the purposes of an example, I've just included a way you could get every date within a certain range in this answer but it really depends on what you're looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.EmployeeName, T.DateToCheck, COALESCE(H.val, A.val, L.val, 'Absent') val
    FROM tblEmployee E
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, number, '2016-09-01') AS DATE)
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE type = 'P'
        AND number <= 3) T(DateToCheck)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'Holiday' val, HolidayDate FROM tblHoliday) H ON H.HolidayDate = T.DateToCheck
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'Present' val, AttendanceDateTime, EmployeeID FROM tblAttendance) A ON CAST(A.AttendanceDateTime AS DATE) = T.DateToCheck AND A.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'Leave' val, LeaveDateTime, EmployeeID FROM tblLeave) L ON CAST(L.LeaveDateTime AS DATE) = T.DateToCheck AND L.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID) T
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR DateToCheck IN ([2016-09-01], [2016-09-02], [2016-09-03], [2016-09-04])) P;
```

The basic logic here is that you want to produce your dates to check, compare those dates to each of the different tables (using left joins or outer applies), get only one result (the logic in this answer uses a coalesce to decide which value it'll show), then pivot the result.

**EDIT:** If you require a `PIVOT` for a dynamic set of column names (e.g. a dynamic date range), you're going to need to use dynamic SQL. Here's one way you could do it:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '', @dateRange VARCHAR(MAX) = '', @startDate DATE = '2016-09-01', @endDate DATE = '2016-09-05';

SELECT @dateRange += ',' + QUOTENAME(DATEADD(DAY, number, @startDate))
FROM master..spt_values 
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY, number, @startDate) <= @endDate;

SELECT @dateRange = STUFF(@dateRange, 1, 1, '');

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.EmployeeName, T.DateToCheck, COALESCE(H.val, A.val, L.val, ''Absent'') val
    FROM tblEmployee E
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, number, ''' + CAST(@startDate AS CHAR(10)) + ''') AS DATE)
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE type = ''P''
        AND DATEADD(DAY, number, ''' + CAST(@startDate AS CHAR(10)) + ''') <= ''' + CAST(@endDate AS CHAR(10)) + ''') T(DateToCheck)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ''Holiday'' val, HolidayDate FROM tblHoliday) H ON H.HolidayDate = T.DateToCheck
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ''Present'' val, AttendanceDateTime, EmployeeID FROM tblAttendance) A ON CAST(A.AttendanceDateTime AS DATE) = T.DateToCheck AND A.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ''Leave'' val, LeaveDateTime, EmployeeID FROM tblLeave) L ON CAST(L.LeaveDateTime AS DATE) = T.DateToCheck AND L.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID) T
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR DateToCheck IN (' + @dateRange + ')) P;';

PRINT @SQL;
EXEC(@SQL);
```

Changing the start and end dates will change the output. You can use the `PRINT @SQL` to see the actual query.

Comment: I'm using below sql to fetch the dates in range : ;WITH DATERANGE AS  
(  
   SELECT DT = DATEADD(DD,0, STARTDATE)  
   WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, STARTDATE) <= ENDDATE  
   UNION ALL  
   SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1, DT)  
   FROM DATERANGE  
   WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, DT) <= ENDDATE  
)  

SELECT * INTO #TMP_DATES 
FROM DATERANGE

Comment: In that case, you could just cross join #tmp_dates instead of doing the cross join I've done. Alternatively, you could modify the current cross join I have to replace '2016-09-01' with @startdate and replace `and number <= 3` with `and dateadd(day, number, @startdate) <= @enddate`

Comment: I can even use your option, I just need to find the range from the input parameters `@startdate` and `@enddate`

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly fine!! But can you please guide me on how to make `([2016-09-01], [2016-09-02], [2016-09-03], [2016-09-04])` dynamic according to the range inputted?

Comment: Making it dynamic would require using dynamic SQL. You would need to dynamically get the date range. I'll edit in an example of how you might do it dynamically.

Comment: Yes this is how I exactly did that :) Thanks a lot for all your help :)